# Identifying if any option has been selected in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a delete button:

I'm trying to first find out if a site has been selected, if a site has been selected i need to determine if one or more list items have been selected and if so proceed to delete those items.

My if statement keeps returning "you must first select your lists" even though they are selected.

```
function deleteList(){
  if(!siteUrl){
    alert("You must first select a site");
    return;
  }else if (siteLists.selectedIndex == null){
    alert('You must first select your list(s)');
    return;
  }else{
    var arrList = siteLists.val(); 
    var listIndex;
    var removeConfirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete these lists?")

    if(removeConfirm){
      for(listIndex = 0; listIndex<arrList.length;listIndex++){
        $().SPSservices({
          operation: "DeleteList",
          webUrl: siteUrl,
          listName: arrList[listIndex],
          completefunc: function(){
            RefreshSiteList(siteUrl);
            alert("Selected lists have been deleted");
          }
        });
      }        
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
    <select id="web_siteLists" style="width:150px;height:150px;" multiple="multiple">
<option value="{041D004F-3BD7-41C2-BE02-F166A6970FDA}">Announcements</option>
<option value="{92E428BF-6F94-47D5-B9EF-446F62827749}">Calendar</option>
<option value="{F8F92E1D-4CF0-4E80-B037-1867BD8A35B2}">Links</option>
<option value="{1E0BD0DF-D4A0-4C27-8F3F-5E4AB4FAFBB4}">Master Page Gallery</option>
<option value="{DF86CAA5-B365-484D-8792-9771E10768E0}">Team List 3</option>
<option value="{5FD4247D-3C54-4D9A-8F0F-E4C374D966B0}">Team List 4</option>
<option value="{E7CBEC72-7A63-414A-8F3C-18579A3FC7D7}">Team List 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: where do you actually define `siteLists`

Comment: I have a ready function that grabs the element: siteLists = $('#web_siteLists');  it's a global variable. I'd get an undefined otherwise.

Comment: are you selecting that on dom ready? if not it won't exist

Comment: Yea I'm declaring and grabbing all my elements on document ready. Let me just run a console log and make sure the right item is returned to double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicated, in the comments, that your variable `siteLists` is a jquery object you need to change: `siteLists.selectedIndex == null){` to

```
if(siteLists.get(0).selectedIndex == -1){
```

As the object won't have that method defined thus null. `.get()` will [Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.](http://api.jquery.com/get/) Change the null to -1. `selectedIndex` will be -1 if you have nothing selected. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R6YM8/

Comment: sorry, what does get(0) do here? I looked at the documentation and it seems to be an AJAX call http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: I tried this but now it's not return an alert when nothing is selected

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/get/ there are two methods named get unfortunatly. i've updated my answer to show that.

Comment: `siteLists.prop('selectedIndex') === -1` would do it, `selecteIndex` is never null.

Comment: Hmm tried it but that also didn't work. It went to the confirmation even though I had no options selected.

Comment: @Batman Have you checked what's returned from `siteLists.prop('selectedIndex')`?

Comment: I checked siteLists not the selectedIndex but after changing from null to -1 it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"I tried this but now it's not return an alert when nothing is selected"

When nothing is selected, the `selectedIndex` property would be `-1`.

Therefore:

```
if (siteLists.prop('selectedIndex') === -1) {/*nothing selected*/}
```